# Python and VBA, mixed end-of-line characters

Tags: python, vba, excel, utf-8

Basically I have a python script saved in a Word document, and I modify it using Excel VBA (insert values from Spreadsheet) and print it onto a .py file , to be run in command line. However, when I print the script in the word document onto .py file and open the .py file, the IDE warns "mixed end-of-line characters that will be automatically fixed", and then all the "" in the script become something like ¡§¡¨¡¨¡¨. Below is my vba code:

```vb
Dim wddoc As Variant
Dim wdApp As Variant
Dim fileopen As String

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
Set wddoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\BLABLA\Desktop\python test\test.docx")

'modifying word document here, inserting value from spread sheet

fileopen = "C:\Users\BLABLABLA\Desktop\python test\testpy.py"

Open fileopen For Append As #1
Print #1, wddoc.Content
Close #1

With wdApp.activedocument
.Close WdDoNotSaveChanges
End With
```

and below is an example of the script saved in word document

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


for i in range(1,10):
    print(“test”)
       “ ”appears to be wrong
```

and below is what I got when I print it onto a .py file:

```py
ï»¿# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

for i in range(1,10):
    print(¡§test¡¨)
    ¡§¡¨appears to be wrong
```

How can I fix that? I am pretty newb and it maybe a silly question but I'll appreciate any input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The strange characters at the start of your file are probably the byte-order-marker.  The quotes -- well, there are a zillion ways to do quotes, and it's not surprising these come out wrong.  Do you _really need_ to program in Word, or can you use a regular program editor?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I need to change the code in python script accroding to the values on an excel spreadsheet. Are there other ways I can modify the python script from Excel VBA?

Comment: Have you tried using the Python xlrd module to read in the spreadsheet from Python?

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer is:

### Never store source code in Microsoft Word

Your end-of-line characters are a mixture of carriage returns, line-feeds, and paragraph-marker characters. Your quote marks are a mixture of single quotes, double-quotes, and mirrored inverted-comma and double inverted-comma quoted-speech markers.

Microsoft Word is helpfully 'autocorrecting' them for you, into the best format for reading and publishing a beautiful business letter in American English.

Gee, thanks, Microsoft... But then again, that's what Word is for: formatted human-readable documents.

Source code is saved in plain text files - .txt or the file type for your language and development environment - and you **never, ever, open a source file in Microsoft Word.**